# Visual Studio Error: name must be a namespace name

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

This is the 3rd question for today as I am still struggling. The problem is: Visual Studio is giving the error on line 2. It says:

> Error: name must be a namespace name

This is my code, this should open the webcam and it should take frames.

What is wrong here?

```cpp
#include "opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap;
    // open the default camera, use something different from 0 otherwise;
    // Check VideoCapture documentation.
    if (!cap.open(0))
        return 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) break; // end of video stream
        imshow("this is you, smile! :)", frame);
        if (waitKey(1) == 27) break; // stop capturing by pressing ESC 
    }
    // the camera will be closed automatically upon exit
    // cap.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Correct the include, should be "#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>"